# Monit: exec a command but don't alert

Tags: configuration, monit

I use monit to start a program when a webserver is not accessible.

`.monitrc`:

```
check host MyServer with address MyServer
  if failed port 80 protocol http then exec "/home/michael/monit/ServerIsOffline.sh"
  else if succeeded then exec "/bin/echo 'Port 80 is accessible again'"
```

It works and executes the script.
But unfortunately it also does an `alert` and sends me an e-mail.

What can I do so that I don't get an mail in case the server is offline?

Comment: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-event-filter

Comment: Thanks for your link. I found it in that documentation :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
check host MyServer with address MyServer
  if failed port 80 protocol http then exec "/home/michael/monit/ServerIsOffline.sh"
  else if succeeded then exec "/bin/echo 'Port 80 is accessible again'"
  noalert mymail@mydomain.de
```

The line `noalert <e-mail-address>` stops mails for this check only.